# Simple Networking Diagram

Tags: networking

http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/8966/wrwrwr.png

What are the IP addresses that flow from A to the router and the addresses that flow from the Router to E?

If the router was reaplced by a bridge, how would the IP address change?

They're teaching us networking in university and it's really really bad, I'm trying to get ahead by looking through textbooks, kind of stuck on this one

Comment: We don't do your homework on here.

Comment: And I'm not asking you to, my whole assignment is a lot bigger, this is just a small part

Comment: If you are having trouble grasping a topic, you should talk with your professor.  This is not the place to ask these types of questions.

Comment: @Cheekaleak - I'm sorry but that's just plain wrong - we will help with homework, but the question has to show some effort, not just copy/paste a question from a textbook. They need to show some effort and prior learning, and ask a specific question, and give full disclosure that it's homework.

Answer (score 1):

1. The address that flow from A would be A's IP of 111.111.111.111
2. The address that flows to E would still be the same source IP, the source and destination IPs don't change unless something like NAT is being used.
3. If the router was a bridge then either:

   1. The subnet mask would have to change so the computers would still be in the same subnet.
   2. The IPs would have to change on one side or the other, again so they're all in the same subnet.

See [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work) <-- Lots of good information.